# How to insert file upload content to database by sending base64 encoded file content via json?

Tags: php, sql, json, python-2.7, advantage-database-server

From my php page I send file upload content as

```
$imgData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
$imgData= base64_encode($imgData);
```

then send this to payload - REST API in python

```
$call->send('{"payload" : { "dbstr" :"' . DEF_DB . '", "tblCode" : "' . USE_INF . '", "use_cod": "'.$use_cod.'", "use_pas": "'.$use_pas.'","use_nam": "'.$use_nam.'","use_dob": "'.$use_dob.'","use_ema": "'.$use_ema.'","use_des": "'.$use_des.'","use_pfe": "'.$imgData.'"}');
```

then in my python code I write like this

```
use_pfe = item_dict['payload']['use_pfe']
imgdata1 = use_pfe.encode("utf-8")
imgdata2 = base64.b64decode(imgdata1)
```

Now I try inserting this to my database using sql where the image column is binary(blob) type

```
cursUserAU.execute("insert into " + tblCode + " (use_cod, use_pass, use_nam, use_dob, use_email, use_desig, use_profile) values ('" + use_cod +"' , '"+ use_pas +"', '"+ use_nam +"', '"+ use_dob +"', '"+ use_ema +"', '"+ use_des +"', "+ imgdata2 +")")
```

but this end in error... Am I doing in right way ? or there any part missing ? I dont want to save this file in any directory I just want to save this directly in db. Please help me with suggestion or any resources. Thanks in advance.

More detials is as follows

I am using adsdb python driver to connect advantage database server database.

in python

```
connUserAU = adsdb.connect(DataSource=datasource, ServerType='3', UserID='adssys', Password='')
cursUserAU = connUserAU.cursor()
sql = "insert into " + tblCode + " (use_cod, use_pass, use_nam, use_dob, use_email, use_desig, use_profile) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cursUserAU.execute(sql, (use_cod, use_pas, use_nam, use_dob, use_ema, use_des, imgdata))
connUserAU.commit()
cursUserAU.close()
```

above use_profile is blob column type

here are the database column types

```
use_cod Char( 10 ),
use_pass Char( 10 ),
use_nam Char( 30 ),
use_dob Date,
use_email Char( 50 ),
use_desig Char( 30 ),
use_profile Blob,
user_gender Char( 1 ),
use_profile2 CIChar( 50 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP code, after you make the call `file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])`, the return value is a string containing the contents of your image, which is *binary* data. You should not be escaping this content as if these were actual characters. So this line should just be:

```
$imgData = file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);
```

Therefore, in your Python code, `use_pfe` will be the base64-encoded image. This will be a string of ASCII characters. The line ...

```
imgdata1 = use_pfe.encode("utf-8")
```

... converts `use_pfe` into a byte string encoded using `utf-8` encoding. But, because this is Python 2 where a byte string is the same thing as a simple character string (that is, type `str` as opposed to a unicode string, that is, type `unicode`) and the characters being encoded are from the ASCII character set, which can be encoded in a single byte, you end up with `imgdata1` being identical to `use_pfe`. In effect, this statement does nothing. However, if this were Python 3, where byte strings, type `bytes`, are different from character strings, which are unicode strings, type `str`, this line would be incorrect: You need to leave the input as type `str` for input to the *next* line, which is converting the base64 string back to a byte string.

Putting this together:

**PHP:**

```
$imgData = file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);
$imgData = base64_encode($imgData);
```

**Python:**

```
use_pfe = item_dict['payload']['use_pfe']
imgdata2 = base64.b64decode(use_pfe)
```

You should be doing your table insert as follows with a *Prepared Statement*, which not only simplifies passing the values but also avoids the possibility of SQL Injection attacks when the values are user-supplied. The place-holders for the arguments below are `?`, which I believe is correct for your database (for MySql and PostgreSQL and most other relational databases, use `%s`).

```
# make it more readable:
sql = "insert into " + tblCode + " (use_cod, use_pass, use_nam, use_dob, use_email, use_desig, use_profile) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cursUserAU.execute(sql, (use_cod, use_pas, use_nam, use_dob, use_ema, use_des, imgdata2))
```

But the above is causing:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Now you *must* provide a complete description of every column in your table `tblCode` including the character set being used. Also, print out for each argument being passed, `type(argument)` For example:

```
print type(use_cod), type(use_pas), type(use_nam), ... type(imgdata2)
```

But to save time, let me ask the most likely cause of the problem: Are you using a BLOB type for column `use_profile`?

Comment: In python I am getting this error ?

cursUserAU.execute("insert into " + tblCode + " (use_cod, use_pass, use_nam, use_dob, use_email, use_desig, use_profile,use_profile2) values ('" + use_cod +"' , '"+ use_pas +"', '"+ use_nam +"', '"+ use_dob +"', '"+ use_ema +"', '"+ use_des +"', "+ imgdata +", '"+ imageProperties +"')")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I've been trying to find documentation on Advantage Database Server and found: under requirements: **Python 2.4 or greater (note that 3.x breaks some functionality and is not supported)**. Well, Python 2 is ancient history; it has reached its "end of life" and no further support is being given to it.

Comment: All other fields as char, date and so on which data insertion works well. ADS support only 2.* version of python.

Comment: Yes use_profile is BLOB type (BInary in ADS) which I am trying to save the image in database like we can do in mysql where image insertion in blob filed.. Am I wrong ? please correct me and thank you for the helping me to find a solution . @Booboo

Comment: First, I asked you to show me the types of *all* the columns. Second, did you modify your INSERT SQL to use my Prepared Statement method instead of what you had? Third, I want to see how *all* the columns are defined. I would also like to see how the database is being connected. What SQL module is being used MySQldb? msql.connector? Something else? What are the connection parameters (I don't care about database name, user id, password, etc. -- just any other options). I can't even be sure which column/variable is causing the problem. Please provide this info by updating your question.

Comment: I have added all in my question (edited) please check .. and thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228205/discussion-between-booboo-and-gopipuli).

Comment: I've added a long comment in chat. Waiting for a response ...